# Rotate according to topmost/last subview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a UITabController that is displayed by becoming a subview of the window (and then animated to slide in):

```
    [self.window addSubview:tabController.view];

    CGRect endFrame = tabController.view.frame;

    CGRect startFrame = tabController.view.frame;
    startFrame.origin.y += [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    tabController.view.frame = startFrame;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        tabController.view.frame = endFrame;
    }];
```

My problem is that I want this subview to not rotate, at all, and be portrait only. Despite  `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` and `shouldAutoRotate` returning false in my `UITabController`'s subview, parts of it still rotate - like the status bar, and the `UINavigationBar` changes size.

Is there a way to fix this, or simply a better way of doing things? Maybe a way to force the statusbar rotation and `UINavigationBar` height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the following in your UITabController:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{ return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrain; }
```

From iOS documentation:

> **Declaring a Preferred Presentation Orientation** 
>   When a view controller
>   is presented full-screen to show its content, sometimes the content
>   appears best when viewed in a particular orientation in mind. If the
>   content can only be displayed in that orientation, then you simply
>   return that as the only orientation from your
>   `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using that and [UIView transitionFromView].